# How to hide the "Username" - "Password" text fields in login screen in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I'm using the social connect plugin for wordpress and want to make the social logins (fb, twitter, stack exchange...) the only option. I looked at various plugins to customize the login page but none of them offered the ability to remove the username and password textfields along with "remember me" checkbox and "forgot your password?" label. Any ideas?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you want to remove password and username text field you must modify the wp-login.php (in your wordpress directory) and remove or comment (comment with `<!--` and `-->` ) this part (line 671 to 708 ):

```
<form name="loginform" id="loginform" action="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php', 'login_post' ) ); ?>" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="user_login"><?php _e('Username') ?><br />
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" class="input" value="<?php echo esc_attr($user_login); ?>" size="20" tabindex="10" /></label>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="user_pass"><?php _e('Password') ?><br />
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" class="input" value="" size="20" tabindex="20" /></label>
    </p>
<?php do_action('login_form'); ?>
    <p class="forgetmenot"><label for="rememberme"><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" tabindex="90"<?php checked( $rememberme ); ?> /> <?php esc_attr_e('Remember Me'); ?></label></p>
    <p class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php esc_attr_e('Log In'); ?>" tabindex="100" />
<?php   if ( $interim_login ) { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="interim-login" value="1" />
<?php   } else { ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo esc_attr($redirect_to); ?>" />
<?php   } ?>
<?php   if ( $customize_login ) : ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="customize-login" value="1" />
<?php   endif; ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="testcookie" value="1" />
    </p>
</form> 

<?php if ( !$interim_login ) { ?>
<p id="nav">
<?php if ( isset($_GET['checkemail']) && in_array( $_GET['checkemail'], array('confirm', 'newpass') ) ) : ?>
<?php elseif ( get_option('users_can_register') ) : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( site_url( 'wp-login.php?action=register', 'login' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Register' ); ?></a> |
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Password Lost and Found' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lost your password?' ); ?></a>
<?php else : ?>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( wp_lostpassword_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Password Lost and Found' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Lost your password?' ); ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>
</p>
<?php } ?>
```

After that you should have only the Wordpress logo and the back link.

Comment: -1, as no one should ever suggest to change WordPress core code, as you need to change it everytime you update WordPress.

Comment: @NishantKumar : Instead of downvoting, propose an other solution. Mine is one among many other even if it's not the best solution.

Comment: I just downvoted to discourage using non-professional programming tactics. We should not propose a solution that is just a fake cover till you don't update WP. I am completely satisfied with your answer but what we should do is just add a note: modifying core code is not suggested and you should do this at your own risk. I state that note in my article even my code is completely legal. See http://www.thebinary.in/blog/wordpress-login-using-email/. I added a note also don't want to hurt anyone so just returned your up-vote...

Comment: I strongly agree with @NishantKumar and this so called "solution" had to be marked as a bad idea. A true solution will not create an even bigger problem i.e. updating WordPress without breaking custom changes to it. Just encouraging people to edit core files is encourage potential security issues that could be costly in time and money.